# neither ... nor

Tags: grammar, neither-nor

Which one is correct?

1. Unfortunately, neither have I finished my work nor my assignment yet.
2. Unfortunately, I have neither finished with my work nor my portfolio yet.
3. Unfortunately, I have neither finished my work nor my portfolio yet.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In "Neither x nor y", keep "x" and "y" parallel in grammar

```
Unfortunately, 
    neither *have I* finished my work 
    nor my assignment 
yet.
```

This first option is unsatisfactory because the "neither" part is a verb-type thing, while the "nor" is a noun.

```
Unfortunately, I have 
    neither *finished* with my work 
    nor my portfolio 
yet.
```

This second option has the same problem: the "neither" option is a verb-type thing.

```
Unfortunately, I have 
    neither *finished* my work 
    nor my portfolio 
yet.
```

Sadly, I don't like this option either, for the same reason.

I suggest a fourth option:

```
Unfortunately, I have finished
    neither my work
    nor my portfolio.
```

You could keep the `yet` at the very end, but I think the sentence is easier to understand without it, because it is easier to see the exact parallelism between the "neither" and the "nor" parts.